# Showing $\hat{F}(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi}F(\theta)e^{-in \theta}d \theta=0$ for $n<0$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $F(\theta)$ is a $2 \pi$-periodic function of $\theta$, the Fourier coeffitcients of $F$ are defined for integer $n$ by $$\hat{F}(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi}F(\theta)e^{-in \theta}d \theta$$ Suppose that $r>1$ and that $f(z)$ is a complex valued function analytic on the disk $$D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}  : |z|<r \}$$ Let $F(\theta)=f(e^{i\theta})$

A) Show that $\hat{F}(n)=0$ for $n<0$, and $$\hat{F}(n)=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$ for $n \ge 0$.

B) Show that the Fourier series $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{F}(n)e^{in \theta}$$ converges to $F(\theta)$ for each $\theta$ with $- \pi < \theta \le \pi$

Any help is greatly appreciated. Having trouble getting started with the problem. Do I have to use Cauchy's Integral formula?

Comment: It's a consequence of the Cauchy integral theorem. The function $\theta \mapsto e^{i\theta}$ is a parametrization of the unit circle.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that $n<0$. Then,

$$\hat{F}(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi}F(\theta)e^{-in \theta}d \theta = 
\hat{F}(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi}f(e^{i\theta})e^{-i(n+1) \theta} ie^{i\theta}d \theta.$$
This is the integral of the function $f(x) x^{-(n+1)}$ along the unitary circle. As this function is analytic, the integral vanishes.

When $n\geq 0$, the [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_integral_formula) says:
$$ \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{(e^{i \theta}-0)^{n+1}} e^{i\theta}d \theta = \frac{2\pi i f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}.$$

It is evident that the series converges absolutely, so it is convergent.

The problem is solved.

Comment: Where did the $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}$ come from in the first line for $\hat{F}(n)$?

Comment: One $i$ was missing, I corrected that: you should multiply and divide by $i$. As the parametrization is $z(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$, the length element is $z'(\theta) = i e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: are we not missing another $i$ for the $dz$ of cauchy's integral formula?